# Problem with copy/paste from clipboard containting comment line in Julia

Tags: interface, julia

copy and paste lines from clipboard which includes a comment line causes problem for the subsequence line (in julia REPL), MWE:

copy and paste the following code is ok:

```
julia> 1+1
julia> 2+2
```

but this isn't

```
julia> 1+1
julia> # comment
julia> 2+2
```

Comment: Hmm, what OS and terminal are you on? Works fine for me. Note that you're not suposed to copy-paste the `julia>` part though!

Comment: I am using OSX Terminal, and the point is to have `julia> ` part

Comment: You misunderstand; `julia>` is what is printed as the julia _prompt_ when you are in the Julia REPL. You do not type that yourself. That would be like trying to type the `$` prompt at the system command. It does not work that way.

Comment: That's the interesting part of REPL, it automatically removes `julia> ` from the text and paste the rest.

Comment: indeed, it should be able to remove  automatically, please file an issue on github

Comment: Seems definitively a bug in the REPL. Opened [an issue](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/43841).

Comment: https://discourse.julialang.org/t/nice-weird-feature-on-pasting-julia-code/15020. But this does not work on Windows, only MacOS and Linux. It certainly does not work on my Windows Julia 1.7 REPL